# Fake MAC Address for old software license

Tags: networking, mac, network-adapter

Win 10 x64.

I have an old software licence that is locked to a MAC address. If I create a VM, and use the Host to define the MAC address on the vNIC, then the software activates normally.

If I use the "Network Address" feature of the vNIC settings to change the MAC, the software somehow figures out the NIC's real MAC and won't activate.

In the end, this solution needs to run on a real PC with a real NIC.

How do I change the MAC on a real NIC in such a way that the software can't read the real MAC. Or how do I install a fake NIC with the MAC address I need for the software to attach to?

(I've installed the MS Loopback Adapter, and set the MAC, but the sofware still finds the 'real' MAC on the adapter).

Comment: If it's tied to the MAC Address you might be breaking your license conditions. How and if you're able to change the MAC might depend on the NIC you're using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, found one of the tools. EEUPDATE is an Intel tool for OEMs to set MAC addresses on system build. I assume such a tool exists for most brands of cards. Tool is OEM only, so need to sign an agreement. Thanks folk!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your software is not actually changing the MAC address of the NIC, only the packets it sends. If and how you can change the MAC depends entirely on the model and firmware. Sometimes (not often)you can change onboard NIC mac addresses in BIOS.

If your current card/NIC cant be reprogrammed, you may be able to purchase a second cheapo card which can be flashed. The model might depend on your pc and available slots, but you want one which supports the "clone mac" function.

Also, if your computer has a WIFI interface you may be able to use the clone mac function on that.